# What is the limit of this product? (SOLVED)

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

What does this limit equal? $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\left(\prod_{n=1}^kn^{2^{k-n}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2^{k-1}-1}}$$

All that I have tried so far is computation and it does seem to converge.  I arrived here because I was wondering about Somos' recurrence relation: $g_n=n\cdot{g_{n-1}^2}$. So $g_5=5^1\cdot 4^2\cdot 3^4\cdot 2^8\cdot 1^{16}$ or $$g_5=\prod_{n=1}^5n^{2^{5-n}}.$$ Now distribute out the terms by taking the {*1+2+4+8*}-th root of $g_5$ (ignore the $1^{16}$ term) so $$\left(\prod_{n=1}^5n^{2^{5-n}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2^{5-1}-1}}.$$

**[UPDATE: Answer Found]** Without ignoring the inclusion of the distribution of the $1^{2^{k-1}}$ term we get Somos' quadratic recurrence constant, $S=1.6616879$. Without the $1^{2^{k-1}}$ term as my original question posed, we get $S^2=2.7612068$.

Comment: Try taking the natural logarithm and using it's properties. What have you already tried?

Comment: *Sequences* converge, not limits.

Comment: @TyO'Brien I suggest you add everything from your comment to your question to avoid possible closure. As it stands now, your question will probably be closed pretty quickly (I'm retracting my close vote in light of your comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the logarithm you get
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{2^k}{2^{k-1}-1} \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{\log n}{2^n} = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\log n}{2^n} $$
which is approximately $1.017468...$. So your limit is approximately $2.76...$